# Latency when calling from one API to another API

Tags: azure, iis, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I have this scenario that I have a external .net Core API gateway that my mobile device talk to and then many individual internal "micro" services that the gateway calls.

My question is for both IIS/Kestrel on local servers and on Azure (since my dev setup is in Azure but production on personal servers).

The question is **if in both cases the calls to the internal api's work out of the box with as little latency as possibel?** Or can I do something to "connect" the external and internal api's to get less latency?

I realy can't find any good data on this so I think I don't have the right terminology for this question.

Hope you can help me shed a light on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: Use the [async/await pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx) in your .NET code when calling remote services. Put services and servers as physically close together as possible to reduce network overhead.

If your code calls some other service over HTTPS, there will always be some latency associated with things like:

- Network stack overhead
- HTTPS handshaking
- Packet routing
- Actually waiting for the remote server to process and return a response

The first two are minimal, and you can't do much about them. The time it takes for a packet to get between two physical locations can vary between 5ms and 200ms (or more), and this is why it's common to place services in the same geographic region or datacenter.

As far as your code goes, as long as you're using the [async/await pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx), your code is already running at the best network speed. If the latency isn't up to your requirements, you'll need to either make your servers faster, or move them closer together.

Fair warning: I'm not a network engineer, and this is a pretty high-level overview. I'd recommend asking technical networking questions over at [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: Ok so say I have the external and internal services on the same IIS next to each other (I don't,just hypothetical) It would always take the hit of your bullet points with just shorter package routing time? I was hoping that for azure e.g I could tell the external api to use the internal ones just like a service layer if you will. Thanks for your answer and your recomendation to post on SF.

Comment: If you're calling a service that's on the same machine, then there is essentially no network and routing latency. I'm not quite sure I follow your question, sorry!

Comment: That is probably just the answer I needed thanks. And the latency when running on same sever or close on the network would be very small, so small it will probably not matter in my case. I can probably find other things in the code and make it faster. Regarding Azure setup I think I have grouped all my services under the same "resource" so they behave as they are on the same server (at least on the same close network). But Ill ask some Azure pro about that.

Comment: @Sturla I agree, that's a good question for an Azure pro. I believe that's the case.